# A question related to geometry of hypersurface

Tags: manifolds, euclidean-geometry

Let $M$ = {$x$ $\in$ $\Re^{n}$; $f(x) = 0$} be a hypersurface described as the zero set of a function $f: \Re^{n} \rightarrow \Re$ with the property that $Df(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in M$. Assume that there is a point $\mathring{x} \in M$ for which the distance to the origin of points on $M$ is minimized. Show that the line connecting the origin and $\mathring{x}$ is perpendicular to $M$ at $\mathring{x}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Lagrange multipliers.

> You are trying to minimize $\|x\|^2$ with the constraint $f(x) = 0$. Lagrange multiplier tells you that at the minimizer the gradients of the cost function $\|x\|^2$ and of the constraint have to be parallel.

Comment: This topic is completely new to me. I have just started to study this topic. I know this may be very elementary question but can you please show me some steps of the solution using Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Did you hover your mouse over the yellow region to see the spoiler?